# Serializing Stanford Parser objects

Tags: java, serialization, stanford-nlp

I've run into an issue that is requiring me to serialize [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) objects (all different sorts) to a file for later use.  As far as I know, none of the Stanford Parser objects implement a serialization interface and I'm wondering: is there a way to serialize a Java object when the object doesn't implement serialization or another process to do the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: First, you should consider what it is, you would like to persist. Second, as far as I can read, most of the objects _are_ serializable. Which objects do you think you cannot serialize. Third, could it be that you are trying to persist some in-between calculations? There might be functionality in the API for doing this.

Comment: @Steen: I'm interested in serializing either the Stanford Parser's `Tree` or `GrammaticalStructure` objects.  Do you have any examples that serialize these objects to a file?  My intent is to write these objects to a file, and in another JVM read the object in at a later time.  I searched through the API and didn't see any tools for doing this - can you point me to the documentation that you mentioned?

Comment: Many of the classes are serializable, but most of the time we persist parses and dependencies as text files.  You might also want to consider that solution.

Comment: @Professor Manning.  I wanted to do exactly that.  However, I didn't find a way to 'cast' a text parse tree or dependencies back into a class.  Am I missing something here?  I found the only way to preserve the object was to serialize it (which works great for my purposes, as well).

Comment: @gnucom: Tree.valueOf(String)

Comment: I don't know what else to say other than, "that is perfect".  Thanks for the parser, by the way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GrammaticalStructure` extends `TreeGraph` that implements `Serializable`, so it is positively the intent of the developers that you should be able to persist objects of this class. `Tree` directly implements `Serializable` and is as such perhaps more suited for persistence (in the eyes of the standford developers).

There is no online API documentation, the information i relay above is taken from the source code of the 1.6.4 (dated 2010-08-20) release of the software. You can download is from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download). It includes javadocs and source code.

Comment: Great example of OOP: thanks for the process.  Thanks a lot for the tip.